# Calculate Mouse Drag Excluding When Text is Selected

Tags: javascript

I've been working on a script that detects drags of the mouse and runs one of two functions if the overall left or right drag was greater than a 100 pixels.

It seems to work well so far, but it gets activated if someone does something like selecting text. I'd like to prevent the script from activating if text is being selected. Is there something I could do to prevent this?

```
var start = 0, distance = 0;
document.getElementById("div").onmousedown = function(e){
    start = e.offsetX;}
document.getElementById("div").onmouseup = function(e){
    distance = e.offsetX - start, start = 0;
    if(distance >= 100) functionOne();
    else if(distance <= -100) functionTwo();}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getSelectedText` method can be used to identify if text is selected or not. depending upon that you can control the business logic

```
function getSelectedText() {
    var text = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type == "Text") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```